# setContentView(View _v) and ViewStub

Tags: android, user-interface, viewstub

I've got the following hierarchy of Activities:

```
public abstract class Base extends Activity {/* common stuff */}
public abstract class Middle extends Base {/* more common stuff */}
public class MyAppActivity extends Middle {/* the app */}
```

The abstract Activities override `setContentView()` and put the given layout into
thier own ones like this:

```
/* Middle activity */
@Override
public void setContentView(int _layoutResID) {
  RelativeLayout middleLayout;
  ViewStub       stub;

  // Inflate middle layout
  middleLayout = (RelativeLayout)
    this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_middle, null);
  stub         = (ViewStub)
    middleLayout.findViewById(R.id.mid_content_stub);

  // Inflate content in viewstub.
  stub.setLayoutResource(_layoutResID);
  stub.inflate();

  // calls Base.setContentView(View)
  super.setContentView(middleLayout); 
}
```

As you can see I use `ViewStubs` to avoid a useless and blown-up hierarchy of container views
in the resulting layout. I'd like to do the same in the abstract `Base` Activity but
since I have to call `setContentView(View)` (notice parameter type) i need to override that one.
Unfortunately it seems like there is no way to use a ViewStub with a view. So I think I have to
replace it like so:

```
/* Base activity */
@Override
public void setContentView(View _view) {
  RelativeLayout baseLayout;
  ViewStub       stub;

  baseLayout = (RelativeLayout)
    this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_base, null);
  stub       = (ViewStub)
    baseLayout.findViewById(R.id.base_content_stub);

  // Replace viewstub with content.
  baseLayout.removeView(stub);
  baseLayout.addView(_view, stub.getLayoutParams());

  super.setContentView(baseLayout);
}
```

Is there a way to use the ViewSub with a View instead of replacing it? I'd like to use it's `inflatedId` in my code. Or is someone aware of a totally different approach I could use to achieve my goals?

Comment: Using a full View would be against the scope of the widget so no, you can't use a view with ViewStub. As you pass through those methods can't you just implement everything in base passing just the id of the user's view? Then in base you could get the first ViewStub and inflate the layout of middle, then get the ViewStub from the middle and inflate the user view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by Luksprog I ended up with a new feature for my `Base` activity:

```
protected void addWrappingLayout(int _layoutID, int _stubID) {
  this.wrapViews.add(new LayoutWithStub(_layoutID, _stubID));
}

@Override
public void setContentView(int _layoutID) {
  LayoutInflater               inflater;
  ListIterator<LayoutWithStub> iter;

  ViewGroup                    layout;
  ViewStub                     stub;
  LayoutWithStub               lws;

  if (this.wrapViews.isEmpty()) {
    // There are no wrapping views.
    super.setContentView(_layoutID);
    return;
  }

  iter     = this.wrapViews.listIterator(this.wrapViews.size());
  lws      = iter.previous();

  inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
  layout   = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(lws.getViewResourceID(), null);

  while (iter.hasPrevious()) {
    stub = (ViewStub) layout.findViewById(lws.getStubID());

    lws  = iter.previous();

    stub.setLayoutResource(lws.getViewResourceID());
    stub.inflate();
  }

  stub = (ViewStub) layout.findViewById(lws.getStubID());
  stub.setLayoutResource(_layoutID);
  stub.inflate();

  super.setContentView(layout);
};
```

Subclasses can register thier layout via `addWrappingLayout(<their layout resource id>, <the stub id in that layout>)` and the `Base` class takes care of it all.